# Vue Router always reloads browser - loosing vuex-state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuex, vue-router

I have a problem, which seemed to be simple but now is not so simple (for me):

I have set up a Vue project with the vue-cli (Router, VueX, PWA). I have set up some routes as always (following straight the recommendations of the documentation) and some state-fields in VueX:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/views/Home.vue'
import Login from '@/views/Login.vue'
import Logout from '@/components/functional/Logout.vue'
import Datapoints from '@/views/Datapoints.vue'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    meta: {
      requiresGuest: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'logout',
    component: Logout
  },
  {
    path: '/project/:id',
    name: 'project',
    component: Datapoints
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (!store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      next({
        path: '/login',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresGuest)) {
    if (store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
      next({
        path: '/',
        query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

In my Views / Components, i use the `push` method on the `$router` instance, to rote programatically, like this:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'home', params: { status: project.response.status, message: project.response.data.error }})
```

, where `project` is the result of an `awaited` axios HTTP request.

## My Problem

Every time i push programatically a new route, or use the `router-view` element, my page reloads (what i want to prevent in a SPA / PWA ...)

My Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    vuetify,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app');
```

I would be happy if anynoe could help me out to *not reload the page on every route change with the Vue router*.

Comment: wouldn't `.push({ name: 'home', params: { status: project.response.status, message: project.response.data.error }})` be identical to result in navigation to `router.push({ path: \`/${project.response.status}/${project.response.data.error}\`)`

Comment: You don't seem to have any `status` and `message` params on your home route

Comment: @Bravo yes, it will be identical, but the problem, that my page refreshes, still remains.

Comment: @LorinIonita what do you mean? I am just passing paramters in the route-path - that shouldn't be a problem. The values do exists (i have checke it too).

Comment: A, ok. I see that you have `project.response.status`. Axios returns the response, so it should be `response.status` or if you assign the response to `project`, `project.status` in your case

Comment: Okay i see, this is a bit confusing because i didn't explain the response. I am using `project.response.status` because it is an error object. So `project` has a `response.status` and `response.data.error` attribute - it is okay. What is just not okay, is the fact that my browser gets refreshed every time and i loose all of my VueX state :D

Answer (score 2):

I think the reload behavior is related to the history mode of your router

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})
```

You can try remove the history mode and see what happens. If you want to keep it, please check with the history mode doc to see if all settings have been done correctly.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you can try using vuex-persistedstate to maintain data in store an it won't change whenever the page is refreshed.

```
`import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate
```

`const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [createPersistedState()]
});`

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate

Comment: Well, in general this is a nice idea, but i will still have the problem that my vue-router will refresh the page - so all of my passed parameters will get lost. Of course this would solve the problem of loosing my vuex-data but it wouldn't solve the other problem. What i could do, is use the persisted state and store all of my current route-params there, but i am more a friend of solving the problems source and not curing it's symptoms :)